# delete method in marketo always return invalid content type

Tags: groovy

I have this code for deleting leads in marketo but I always get an error saying that I had invalid content type I used the same method using the post and get and it works but in delete it keeps returning the error:

```
def client = new RESTClient('https://XXX-XXX-XXX.mktorest.com')
client.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx:xx"
def response = client.delete(path:'/rest/v1/leads.json',
        contentType : 'application/json' )
println response.data
```

response:

```
[errors:[[code:612, message:Invalid Content Type]], requestId:36df#14c6da14e9e, success:false]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not sending any payload. Has the payload been omitted from the excerpt?

The particular API is documented [here](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/delete-lead/). Have a close look at the payload structure as it is a required property (the list of lead IDs to be deleted).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there who needs to know what the payload to delete leads on the Marketo REST API should look like, here is a sample.

You can delete multiple leads by adding more objects with the "id" property to the "input" array.

```
{
  "input": [
    {
      "id": 123456789
    },
    {
      "id": 123456790
    }
  ]
}
```